# Where is my sqflite database stored inside Flutter app?

Tags: flutter, dart, sqflite

I'm creating an encrypted sqflite database with [sqflite_sqlcipher](https://pub.dev/packages/sqflite_sqlcipher) and would like to open it with the [DB Browser for SQLCipher](https://sqlitebrowser.org/). For that i only need to find my .db file but I can't seem to figure out where this file is stored inside my app.
I have printed the path to the db in my init function and the output is below:

```dart
Future<Database> _initDatabase() async {
  print("Database path: ${await getDatabasesPath()}");
  final dbPath = await getDatabasesPath();
  final path = join(dbPath, "documents.db");
  final pw = await getPassword();

  return await openDatabase(
    path,
    password: pw,
    version: 1,
    onCreate: _onCreate,
  );
}
```

`Database path: /data/user/0/com.example.did/databases`

Answer (score 2):

You could access it using Android Studio, look for *Device File Manager* and from there, you can access the file path.